# Inverse limit of $\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, limits-colimits

In the wikipedia article about the [inverse limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit) it is stated that for a prime number $p$
$$\varprojlim_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z},$$
where the arrow between the groups $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}$ is given by multiplication by $p$.

I don't quite understand that: I interpret this "multiplication by $p$" as $[x]_{p^n} \mapsto [px]_{p^{n+1}}.$ But shouldn't the arrows point in the other direction from $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ for the inverse limit to make sense? On the other hand if one interprets it as a direct limit, then the arrows become inclusions and the limit is simply the group of all roots of unity of order $p^n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I also find it a bit odd that one can get a "continous" object from "discrete" objects without invoking any topological notions at all.

How can this be reconciled, is this direct limit correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is false (I'll correct it on Wikipedia). The correct statement is that the *direct* limit / filtered colimit of $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$ with these maps is the [Prufer $p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1}{p} \right]/\mathbb{Z}$, which is the subgroup $\mu_{p^{\infty}}$ of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ consisting of $p$-power roots of unity. The inverse limit / cofiltered limit (with a different set of maps going the other way, namely the quotient maps $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$) is the [$p$-adic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

There's a reason people don't take inverse limits over diagrams that are "increasing to the right" like this diagram is:

$$\mathbb{Z}/p^0\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{p} \dots$$

and it's that the inverse limit over any such diagram is its first term.

The solenoid example is also wrong (and I will also correct it). $\mathbb{R}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$ is not a ring because $p^n \mathbb{Z}$ is not an ideal. You can in fact prove that [every compact Hausdorff ring must be totally disconnected](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+Hausdorff+rings+are+profinite), or equivalently must be profinite, so rings like the $p$-adic integers are all you get.

Comment: By the way do you understand the $\Bbb{Z_p/Z}$ [appearing there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit#Mittag-Leffler_condition) ?

Comment: @reuns: it comes from writing down the $\lim^1$ long exact sequence with $A_i, B_i, C_i$ exactly as written. You get $0 \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_p \to \lim^1 \mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z} \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now. Maybe that wasn't the best "example" to begin grokking the inverse limit after all...

Comment: Ah yes and I see your eddit about the solenoid example, that was one I also wanted to understand... Great, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jannik: I think the best example to start with is the $p$-adic integers. Very rich example!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yeah, I looked into that, but the possibility of constructing the circle group as a limit of "discrete circle groups" really allured me.